# Css class value substitution

Tags: css

Is it possible in CSS to define a class that is a reference to other css classes?

Example

**main.css**

```
// this is just a pseudo code for the lack of the proper command if it exists
.a {
  #ref: '.b, .c'
}
```

**plugin.css**

```
.b {
  color: red;
}
.c {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

**index.html** *imports main.css and plugin.css*

```
<div class="a">Hello</div> <!-- a should be substituted or resolved to .b and .c -->
```

Answer (score 1):

not without a pre-compiler like sass or less.

without a pre-compiler you can specify multiple classes and give each of them some specific css attributes

```
<span class="mycolors myfontsize">text</span>

.mycolors {
    color: red;
}
.myfontsize {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

or you can comma separate multiple classes in the css to apply some properties to all of the classes

```
.a,.b,.c {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, to the OP, I think this is what you're looking for. Personally, I prefer LESS because their variable syntax is easiest. You can declare a `@variable` and call it as a value later one. Ex: `@color: #555;` > `.class { background-color: @color;`

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.

But as long as you are simply combining different properties you can still combine them from different stylesheets, like

```
class_a {
  color: green;
}
```

in Stylesheet 1 and

```
class_a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

in Stylesheet 2 will add up both properties + settings for tags which have the class attribute `class_a` if both stylesheets are referenced after each other.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation